# Symfony messenger failed messages with extra information/flags

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-messenger

I've been searching around for a possibility to flag or add additional information to Symfony Messenger message if it fails. For example: If a message fails to finish completely, I would like to add a flag to the message like `emailSent = true` so if it would retry, I could check if that flag is set and skip that part of the code which sends the email.

Is this possible? If not, maybe you could suggest what approach I could take? Thank you.